# Seeking Advice on Importing Roasted Specialty Coffee Beans from Brazil into the US: Permitting and Legal Requirements

Tags: business

I'm a Brazilian currently residing in the United States, and I'm exploring the idea of importing specialty coffee beans roasted in my hometown in Brazil to sell here in the US market. My hometown is renowned for producing unique and high-quality coffee, and I believe there's a niche market for it here.

However, I'm encountering challenges navigating the complex process of permits and legal requirements associated with importing roasted goods into the US. Despite conducting some initial research, I still feel overwhelmed and unsure about the necessary steps to take.

I've come across suggestions to hire a customs broker to assist with the process, but the associated costs seem prohibitive, especially for someone like me who is at the initial stages of starting a business.

Therefore, I'm reaching out for insights and advice. Do you have any experience or expertise in importing goods into the US, particularly in the realm of specialty food products such as roasted coffee beans?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, tips, or resources you can offer to help me navigate this journey more effectively.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and support!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to what you asked, but perhaps an alternate approach.

What makes the beans unique is the beans, themselves. The roasting process can be replicated anywhere (by someone with the equipment and skill, which can be replicated anywhere).

If stored properly, the raw beans will last a very long time without degradation. But once they're roasted, they have a very short shelf life.

I don't know what's legally required to import raw beans, and how that would be different from importing roasted goods. But some considerations:

- Raw beans could be shipped in bulk by comparatively inexpensive methods (boat), and be used up over a long time. Roasted beans would need fast transportation (air), in small enough quantities to be used up soon after arrival. This would add significant costs that would put you at a competitive disadvantage for business purposes.
- Any form of import will require inspection on arrival by Customs. This would not affect raw beans. Roasted beans would need to be kept in sealed containers until use. Opening any container for inspection would ruin all the coffee in the container.

Importing raw beans might leave you with similar kinds of regulatory questions to answer. But at least that might put you on a better track as a business idea, and the information might be easier to track down.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your perspective. The biggest reason I was considering starting with imported roasted beans from a supplier I trust in Brazil, was to mitigate some initial risks, especially in terms of avoiding upfront investment in equipment and labor for roasting here in the US. This approach would allow me to focus more on establishing the business and building the brand without the immediate need for roasting infrastructure.

Comment: However, as you rightly pointed out, there are additional costs and complexities associated with importing roasted beans, including transportation logistics, shelf life considerations, and potential regulatory hurdles. These factors can certainly impact competitiveness and profit margins.